# spring-xd how to create stream with multi processor

Tags: spring, spring-xd

I have a question is how to create stream with multi processor. For ex:

```
stream create --name multiModuleTest --definition "tcp | processor1 | processor2 |file" --deploy
```

Or

```
stream create --name multiModuleTest --definition "(tcp, http) | processor1 | processor2 | (file,log)" --deploy
```

Please tell me how to do that? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Fire up multiple containers and use the [deployment manifest](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#deployment-manifest) to set the module `count`.

If you want to multiprocess within a processor instance, change the `input` channel to an `ExecectorChannel`. Docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#executor-channel) and [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-configuration-executorchannel).

Comment: Added info about `ExecutorChannel`.